# SQL GroupBy to show one row with max value in one row

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have following table

```
 ID    Date  quantity storename  
 id1 01-01  1       A1  
 id2 01-03  3       A2  
 id1 01-03  40      A2
```

I want to see

```
 ID    Date  quantity storename  
 id1 01-03  40       A2  
 id2 01-03  3        A2
```

So basically I would like to groupby ID and find the max(newest) date. Then get the entire row data from that max(newest) date.

I tried the following code and it's not working out.

```
SELECT ID, max(Date), quantity, storename FROM table
GROUPBY ID
```

Also, is it possible to get all the columns(Like using *) instead of specifying one by one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2);
```

Do be sure that the date does not have a time component.  If it does:

```
select t.*
from t
where trunc(t.date) = (select trunc(max(t2.date)) from t t2);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you so much for the quick response.
My question is about the max(quantity), since I only care about the max(date), the quantity can be whatever as long as the quantity is coming from the max(date) row. 
Let's say for the first table row 3 is id1 01-03  -10      A2  instead, the results will return as id1 01-03  -10     A2 
Does it help?

Comment: @SwagZ . . . That question seems much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like this:

```
select *
from (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                (
                    PARTITION BY
                        tbl.ID

                    ORDER BY
                        tbl.date desc

                ) AS RowNumber,
                *
            from
                tablename as tbl
        ) tmp
where tmp.RowNumber = 1
```

The partition by will group your data and then order it by the field(s) you want.  You can include as many group bys (partition by) or order bys as you would like by using a comma to separate them.